# How to pull all data from yesterday with a DATETIME field

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to pull data specifically from yesterday with a date/time field. I keep getting errors. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

What I need is all rows with a CustomerPurchaseDateTime with yesterday's date.

Here's my WHERE statements:

**Example:**

```
AND CAST(v.CustomerPurchaseDateTime AS DATE) >= DATEADD(DAY, -1,
CONVERT(v.CustomerPurchaseDateTime,GETDATE()))
```

**Error for example:**
*Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
The multi-part identifier "v.AdmitDtm" could not be bound.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
Type v.AdmitDtm is not a defined system type.*

Note: I don't have you use the posted example. I just posted it to give some context of where I am.

Comment: The problem is in your JOIN clause, not where clause.

Comment: error saying this v.AdmitDtm is not available

Comment: The error you posted has nothing to do with the code you posted. Please edit your question to include your full query.

Comment: I would suggest posting the entire code instead of two lines.  You know the error has something to do with the table aliased 'v'.  So why not post the code for v?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `CONVERT` incorrectly. But assuming that CustomerPurchaseDateTime is a datetime you can simply do this:

```
WHERE v.CustomerPurchaseDateTime >= CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```

On `2018-11-05 12:34:56` the above will check dates `>= 2018-11-04 00:00:00`

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly defined table as v otherwise it gives error as shown below.

```
select v.* from YourTable v
```

Here v is alias for the table. Without alias you can not use v..
You can use dateadd function in date column to get the yesterday date as shown below.

```
select DATEADD(dd, -1, getdate())
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This error can also come when you are trying to access v.ContactNo in query where ContactNo is not in either table or not in the table after joining.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, look at this partial expression from the code in the question:

```
CONVERT(v.CustomerPurchaseDateTime,GETDATE())
```

That makes no sense. It's not how to call the convert function. The first argument, where you have `v.CustomerPurchaseDateTime`, is supposed to be a data type, like `date` or `datetime`. Even a string value like `'date'` is not right. This then confuses the larger `DATEADD()` function call, to the point where I'm not sure what Sql Server will try to do with it any more, and I suspect when you fix your error you'll end seeing another one for this line.

But I wouldn't write this that way in the first place.

Avoid calling functions like `CONVERT()` or `CAST()` on values in the table when you can. Calling a function like that breaks any indexes on the column that might help the query, which cuts to the core of database performance. Additionally, you will always need to call that function for *every row in the table*, even rows that won't be shown in the results. In this case, you can avoid using the function on values in the table like this:

```
WHERE v.CustomerPurchaseDateTime >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1 current_timestamp) AS DATE)
```

or if you ever record future purchases/pre-orders in this table:

```
WHERE v.CustomerPurchaseDateTime >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1 current_timestamp) AS DATE) 
  AND v.CustomerPurchaseDateTime <  CAST(current_timestamp AS DATE)
```

Both of those still call a function (`CAST()`), but they call it using the  `current_timestamp` value (same as `getdate()`, but more cross-platform and standard), such that it's effectively a constant. Neither of my options needs to do any calculations on values actually stored in the table. They only call the functions *once for the entire query*, rather than once per row, and don't interfere with indexing.

**But the error posted in the question has nothing to do with any of this.**

The error is complaining about an `AdmitDtm` column, which is not shown in any of the code in the question. You should look for where that column is used, and make sure the syntax in that area is correct, too.

Answer (score 0):

The `CONVERT` function syntax seems to be wrong.

You need to specify datatype to convert first like below:

```
CONVERT( datatype, expression [, style] )
```